# Relation between curvature of spin connection, Weyl spinor and the cosmological constant

Tags: gravity, spinors, duality

Consider the chiral version of Einstein-Cartan gravity. What is the relation between the self-dual part of the curvature of the spin connection $F^{AB}$, the cosmological constant $\Lambda$ and the Weyl spinor $\psi_{ABCD}$? What is the background field equation for an arbitrary Einstein background and for an instanton background?